# How to express REQUEST / START action via redux-actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux-actions

I want use redux-actions to simplify my react-redux code, but I got a question:

Say I got "load" action, which fetch some topics from remote. so the code would be:

```
const load = createActions('LOAD');

export function fetch() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(fetchTopicsRequest());   // <- here is my question.
    return network
      .request('/topics?' + qs.stringify(getState().topics.filter.options))
      .then(network.handleResponse)
      .then(result => dispatch(load(result)))     // <- here I got the topics in the payload
      .catch(error => dispatch(load(error)));     // <- here I got the errors in the payload, in the reducer I check on the "error" field to see if the request successed.
  };
}
```

I think it's good to have the result and error been dispatched with one action. but how about express the "Requesting" status with the same action ?  as the code above I didn't figure it out, so I have to made another action "fetchTopicsRequest()", this makes the whole code seems so weird.

From the early disscusion I noticed that there use to be a “status” field, It could be handy in such case. where did it go? or I just missed some better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to correct your understanding of what you're calling as actions. In your case the function `fetch()` is an action creator which is capable of dispatching actions, `load(result)` and `load(error)` are the actual actions being dispatched.

Now, as you're looking for a better implementation of your `fetchTopicsRequest()` action so I would suggest you to use the conventional way of writing an action. In your case that would be something like this:

```
dispatch({type: 'FETCHING_TOPICS'});
```

Now you can capture this action in your reducer and do whatever while your `topics` are fetching.

**UPDATE:**

To handle the `pending` case you can use the composition of action and reducer. Once the `FETCHING_TOPICS` actions is dispatched then in your reducer you can mark `pending` as `true` and once the `response` is received then you can change `pending` to `false` like this:

```
function reducer(state={pending: null}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'FETCHING_TOPICS':
      return {...state, pending: true};
      break;
    case 'FETCHED_TOPICS':
      return {...state, pending: false, //payload if any};
      break;
    case 'FETCHING_ERR':
      return {...state, pending: false, //payload if any};
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, your right. I can further correct it: the `load(result)` and `load(error)` are also action creators, the true action is the plain object actually been dispatched. 

What I want say is, there is an `error` field stand for the action's status, but there is no way to express `pending` status. If I need to know such status, what is the best way to express it ?

Comment: The best way to handle such case is to use the combo of actions and reducers. So when you're dispatching the ```FETCHING_TOPICS``` action, you can mark ```pending``` as ```true``` in your reducer and when you're dispatching either ```result``` or ```error``` actions then you can change ```pending``` to ```false``` in your reducer. I'll update the answer to be a bit more verbose.

Comment: Sorry, pal. I think I didn't make it clear that I'm talking about `redux-actions`. the library for reduce boilerplate code. I know the three-actions pattern, I just want use redux-actions to simplify my code base.